# Display Page Load Time in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

How can I display the page load time in the view, similar to how the log file shows "Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 16.8ms | Models: 0.497ms)"

Comment: All is here, what do you want more ?

Comment: I think he means displaying the time in the view when you look at it in a browser.. not from the logs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to use Seconds better:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :set_start_time

  def set_start_time
    @start_time = Time.now.to_f
  end

end
```

View Code:

```
Page Rendered in <%= sprintf('%.3f', (Time.now.to_f - @start_time) ) %> seconds
```

Comment: This will often result in negative values, since `usec` wraps around to zero every second.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this.. add a before_filter to your application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :init

  def init
    @start_time = Time.now
  end
end
```

in the view (I am using HAML):

```
load_time=#{Time.now-@start_time} seconds
```

This is not going to be exactly the same as the time you see in the logs, since it's only from the before_filter to the place where it was called in the view, but it should be close.

Comment: and of course this is kinda ugly in the view, just showing this for simplicity.  You would want to put that in a helper

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the below railcast video you'll get to know all your concerned details.

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler?view=asciicast
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) which adds a little badge to the top of the page showing all the details of the rendering speed.